# Hyperledger Fabric: are there other network types, besides a channel?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In the Hyperledger Fabric contract API there is the function:

```
gateway.getNetwork
```

which, in the papernet tutorial, is used to get a "channel".

Are there other types of networks, besides "channel"?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, it should only return channels.
https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/Gateway.html#getNetwork

Comment: +1 for the link. But from there I read that the returned object is of type "Network". Apparently, channels are networks and vice versa ... ? I find this somewhat confusing.

Comment: yes, Network is object representation of a channel.